# Creating a UV mesh to a specific shape

Tags: mesh, uv

I have recently started using blender for work, with the idea being to show the customer their sticker kit design on the go kart bodywork.

I have modelled the bodywork with a certain degree of success, but am having trouble creating the UV mesh. The difficulty being, I need the UV mesh to match as closely as possible the 2D representation, so minimal manipulation of the 2D image is required.

The image below shows the 3D model of the front bodywork, the 2D shapes I am trying to match, and what the final product should look like.

Any ideas on how to create the mesh will be very much appreciated. I have also tried creating the shape of the sticker in blender and shrink wrapping it onto the bodywork, but with little success.

Hopefully this explains the problem well enough. If you need any more information, I'll do my best to answer any questions.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "UV mesh"? UV is often meant as UV map used for unfolding mesh into 2D space to map 2D textures which any mesh can have, is it related here? Do you want to be able to choose a color for the certain parts on the final product easily?

Comment: Yes, I did mean UV map. The idea is to transfer a design done in Illustrator or similar onto the 3D bodywork. The design is created using the template with the magenta outlines in the middle image. This is what will be printed, cut out and applied to the bodywork in real life. I would like to create a digital representation of the final design on the bodywork.

Comment: In this case you could use Export UV Layout feature in UV editor (see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout), import resulting image to Illustrator, add it there as layer and adjust there your design as required according to UV map (UV map should be done appropiately so that you can understand which area is which island). Then once you assign the texture onto the mesh it will be mapped correctly, this is how texturing outside of Blender is often done

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but with the current mesh I cannot mark the seams in the places I need to. Should I recreate the model or, is there a way of creating a seam where there currently mesh lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a seam where there currently mesh lines"? If there isn't geometry required for seam to be placed then no other way to place seam other than remodeling. There is an [addon for unfolding mesh like papercraft](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/is-there-a-way-to-unfold-a-mesh?rq=1) but looks like you want to do the other way around

Comment: Sorry, I am doing a very bad job of explaining myself. 
"creating a seam where there currently mesh lines" - I mean I have been creating the UV map by adding seams to the mesh that standard way of selected edges and 'marking as seam' then UV unwrapping the mesh.

Yes I would like the shape of the 2D design to dictate the unwrapped shapes in the UV map.

I will try remodeling making sure I create geometry in the correct place. 
Thanks for your input.