# Matching blender dimensions to paper cutout

Tags: modeling, add-on, measurement

I just discovered that you can export your blender model as a paper model, that you can later cut out.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2353/75504

Github: https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender

Home page: https://blenderartists.org/t/export-paper-model/476597

I tried it and for some reason no matter what I do the dimensions in blender don't match with the real model. Is there a way to deal with this, or do I have to just accept it?

Comment: I dont know why people are closing your Q, but would be better to change title. There is no issue with blender, but with specific blender addon.

Comment: There is an add-on for blender specifically for making paper models - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2353/75504 - Scroll down a bit for the github link for 2.8

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think he is referring exactly to this addon

Comment: Maybe the reason of the problem was unapplied scale. Object mode > object selected > Ctrl+A > Scale. It can mess up measurements in Blender if unapplied, especially if it was uneven before applying (eg. 0.2 by X; 2.5 by Y axes)

Comment: @vklidu I voted to close re lacking detail and clarity, eg a link to the addon, perhaps description of an attempt and the expected result vs "real" result. and yeah the title.  Possibly harsh, flitter between commenting, editing and voting to close.

Comment: If this is about an add-on, can you change the title, or at least put an add-on tag?

Comment: @batFINGER you are right, just for a new contributor -I dont see notification to improve Q ... probably it cames after closing? Will check the system.

Comment: Will find `noobs` toe the line better if you beat them with the close stick.... (lol)  Most important IMO is the link, others who read this question who are interested  and henceforth desire to know more about paper folding can find the link to the addon  searching the comments above. .. and suggested edit to the question.  (Forgive me, it's late)

Comment: @batFINGER I agree, if Q wouldnt be asked better, close it :)

Comment: Sigh, edited.  Hopefully it is the addon in question 8^)-

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos - batFinger already added the details it seems to me improved enough. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

*Tried with a Cube and seems to be working.
But there is one thing that could be good to discuss with developer of this addon on [Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/export-paper-model/476597)*

---

**Cube**

- Object *Dimension* set 0.2 m
- Object *Scale* is always better to have a 1 (*Apply Scale* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

[image]

**Addon**

- press *Unfold*
- or select edges press *Mark as Seam* and press *Unfold*

Export (or skip for now)

- *Model Scale* 1
- *Page Size* 1 m

[image]

When export window popups go to options (right up gear icon)

- **it seems addon does not respect export setup from 3Dview**
- by default addon change scale automatically to fit A4 paper format

[image]

- change scale to 1
- if format is not enough for unfolded object it warns you

[image]

- change paper format, addon will inform you if it is enough

[image]

[image]

Comment: emu (author) is going to care about mentioned functionality https://blenderartists.org/t/export-paper-model/476597/478?u=vklidu