# "Unfolding" a low-poly mesh without distorting it. I wanna build the result from paper but after using a standard UV-unwrap, nothing fits anymore

Tags: uv

Basically the title.

I have a Low-Poly Mesh (of an Elephant head). Maybe about 25 faces. If I UV-unwrap it and then print/cut up the result with paper, nothing fits together because it was distorted (even if I manually placed the seams).

Is there a way to stop that behaviour so that a face on the model keeps its shape in the 2D-projection? (of course I know this only works with flat faces, not curves like a globe. But as I said, my model conforms to that).

Anyone got a tip? I realize its a pretty specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

there's a nice addon included in blender for that...
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/paper_model.html

Comment: also this has been asked before like [in this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/is-there-a-way-to-unfold-a-mesh)