# How to export an UV layout with the same size as the original 3D object

Tags: uv, export, transforms, svg, dimensions

I'm using the UV unwrap function to get the 2D template of my 3D object.

After this I export the UV layout as an .svg so I can reload this in blender and make a mesh out of it which can be used for 3D-printing.

When I import the svg in blender it turns out to be very very small. Is there a method in which I can keep my 2D layout of exact the same size as the original 3D object? Or is there somewhere where can I find the scaling of the object so I can manually change it to the right size again?

It is very important for me to make a 2D mesh with exact the same size as the original 3D object. I attached a picture of the 3D model and UV layout, as can be seen it is not a difficult object.

[image]

Comment: There is no correlation between UV layout units and object size. UV Layouts use a [0 to 1 coordinate space bound to image size](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66727), and stretches along with it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/is-there-a-way-to-unfold-a-mesh

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I understand you correctly, there is no way I can get my 2D model in exact the same size/dimension as my 3D object? Even not after importing it as .svg and scaling it manually (in that case I need to know the scaling factor)? How do other people do this when they have to 3D print a wrap with specific measurements (fitting the object)?

Comment: There are workarounds but probably non of them are very accurate. It is also not possible to guarantee unwrapping every arbitrary shape without distortions or overlaps. See the link above for alternatives.

Comment: @Maartje Of course you can manually scale the svg, let's say you have the length of one edge of a certain face, then you can measure the length of the corresponding edge in the UV layout and calculate the scaling factor. **But:** UVs can be stretched, not only to fit an image mentioned above, but also when parts are connected in a flat 2D layout although bulged in 3D, then the edges may be unproportionally varying in length. To avoid that completely you would have to separate all faces from each other in UV layout. Or at least each face should only have one mutual edge with another face.