# How to make UV map size same as actual model scale

Tags: uv

I'm trying to make a planar figure using a UV map, but the shape is not the same as the model. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277242/how-to-export-an-uv-layout-with-the-same-size-as-the-original-3d-object

Comment: If you need a 0-stretch UV map /  mapped geometry, that may not be geometrically possible without splitting all faces. . Could you please illustrate what kind of unwrap is acceptable? Tell us what the planar figure is for?